# Filter by AGE in repository layer

Tags: c#, api

In my API, I have two parameters for my filter, `MinAge` and `MaxAge`.
In my Database in my DateOfBirth column that saves Utc datetime, I want to search all records with the player age is in that range (`MaxAge` | `MinAge`).

```
public async Task<PagedList<Player>> GetAll(Guid clubId, PlayerParameters playerParameters, bool trackChanges)
{
    List<Player> players = await FindByCondition(p => p.ClubId.Equals(clubId), trackChanges)
        .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
        .Skip((playerParameters.PageNumber - 1) * playerParameters.PageSize)
        .Take(playerParameters.PageSize)
        .ToListAsync();

    int count = await FindByCondition(p => p.ClubId.Equals(clubId), trackChanges).CountAsync();

    return new PagedList<Player>(players, count, playerParameters.PageNumber, playerParameters.PageSize);
}
```

How can i search?
playerParameters.MinAge
playerParameters.MaxAge

Comment: One option, calculate the dates required for the min and max and query using the calculated date. A second option, create a Calculated column in your DB (if it supports it) and run you query against the new column.

Comment: The LINQ query will be translated to SQL. Therefore, `Equals` will not be called (this code is actually never executed) and you can simply write `p => p.ClubId == clubId`.

Comment: I actually tested it and it was executed, my doubt is really about the search by age

Comment: If you are using a object relational mapper like EF (the parameter `bool trackChanges` makes me assume this), then the LINQ-to-EF query creates an expression tree that is never executed but translated into SQL. E.g. `Where` returns an `Expression<Func<TSource,Boolean>>`, not a `Func<TSource,Boolean>` as it would with a LINQ-to-Object query.